# Identify object name into eventfilter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to identify object name and perform some operation. is there any name to make sure if we are in proper widget. or identify widget name

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtGui import (QTextCharFormat, QIcon, QKeySequence,
                           QBrush, QColor, QTextDocument, QFont,
                           QTextCursor, QTextBlockFormat, QFontDatabase)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QPlainTextEdit, QSizePolicy, QApplication, QLabel, QGridLayout, QMessageBox, QToolBar, QTextEdit, QCheckBox, QAction,
                               QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView, QMenu,
                               QWidget)
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QRegExp, QFile, QTextStream, QRect
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout,
                               QPlainTextEdit, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
                               QListWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
                               QMenuBar, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QDialog,
                               QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QFormLayout,
                               QCheckBox, QDialogButtonBox,
                               QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHeaderView)
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super().__init__()


    def create_widget(self):
        self.plain_textedit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plain_textedit.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.plain_textedit.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.another_textedit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.another_textedit.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.another_textedit.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plain_textedit)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.another_textedit)
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.window.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.plain_textedit.viewport():
            print ("plain_1")
        elif obj is self.another_textedit.viewport():
            print ("plain_2")
            #Reseting format for single click when user use shift+click select data

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window(app)
    window.create_widget()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: want to perform some operation based on obj type...

Comment: I don't understand you, I think your code distinguishes one object from another in evenfilter so I don't understand where your code fails.

Comment: You actually want to do it based on *identity*, not type. In Python, the `is` operator is the correct way to do that. There aren't any better options.